# Customize legend to display in vertical + horizontal EXTJS

Tags: extjs, charts

i'm using Columns Chart.
Simply legend=true,
then it's display in horizontal manner, if i set to vertical then it's set all data in vertical manner.
but need to do that is,display legend in both way,e.g

1)data 1 2)data 2

3)data 3 4)data 4

5)data 5.

it's is possible to make customize legend like this.
Thank's in advance!

Comment: i found SmartLegend.js that is helpful but it's only working in PIE CHART i need it with "Column Chart"

Comment: problem is solved,but now we want without using SmartLegend